# import android.widget.menu; error: cannot find symbol(menu)

Tags: android, build.gradle

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.menu;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.viewbinding.ViewBinding;
import com.example.knowyoursoil.R;
import java.lang.NullPointerException;
import java.lang.Override;

public final class NavMenuBinding implements ViewBinding {
@NonNull
private final menu rootView;

private NavMenuBinding(@NonNull menu rootView) {
this.rootView = rootView;
}
@Override
@NonNull
public menu getRoot() {
return rootView;
}

@NonNull
public static NavMenuBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater) {
return inflate(inflater, null, false);
}
```

It's give me this error and this code is inside NavMenuBinding.java file
error: cannot find symbol(menu)

symbol:   class menu

location: package android.widget

Comment: Java is case-sensitive. Use `android.widget.Menu`, with a capital `M`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably created your XML file in the `res/layout` directory. Instead, create the menu directory in res:

[image: Screenshot showing the creation of the res/menu directory]

Then move your menu XML file to that folder.

[image: Screenshot showing the menu resource relocated to res/menu/bottom_nav_menu.xml]